# Filtrar saida do cmd com VBS e retornar valor

Tags: script, cmd, filtro, vbs, vbscript

tenho em meu ambiente o ArcServe Backup, que é o programa de backup em fita que utilizamos, nele temos um programa chamado ca_qmgr que gerencia as filas dos jobs de backup, com um parametro via CMD consigo que ele me retorne os status dos jobs atuais como na figura abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o script que utilizei para me retornar esta saida é o seguinte :

```
strCMD = ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\ca_qmgr.exe"" -list")

strResultado = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(strCMD).StdOut.ReadAll

wscript.echo strResultado
```

O que preciso agora é o seguinte, pegar o valor do campo LAST-RESULT e caso qualquer um dos jobs esteja no status "FAILED" me retorne o valor numerico 1, e caso todos estejam ok me retorne o valor numerico 0, tentei mas nao consegui alguem tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Poderias usar seu **`vbs`** mas criado por um **`bat`**

**2)** O mesmo **`bat`** ´pode chamar a execução do seu **`vbs`**

**3)** Na saída da execução do **`vbs`** você filtra as strings ecoando **0 ou 1**

---

```bat
@echo off 

>"%temp%\Filtra_Saida.vbs"^
    (
    echo/ strCMD = ^("""C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\ca_qmgr.exe"" -list"^)
    echo/ strResultado = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^).Exec^(strCMD^).StdOut.ReadAll
    echo/ wscript.echo strResultado
    )

set _CScript="%Windir%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo & cmd /v/c set _Filtrar=!_CScript! "%temp%\Filtra_Saida.vbs"

:: Para listar um 0 ou um 1  apenas, e por execução use ::
%_Filtrar%|find "FALIED" >NUL && echo/1||echo/0

rem  ---------------------------------------------------- 

:: Para listar todas as ocorrências com 0 e 1 por linha, use linha abaixo ::  
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ('%_Filtrar%')do echo/%%i|find "FALIED" >nul && (echo/1)||(echo/0)

2>nul del /q /f "%temp%\Filtra_Saida.vbs"
```